# Django populate the admin fields list after checking a condition

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-views

I am checking if the value of a field say short_text1 is equal to 1 in the assosiative model then i populate the **LabelAdmin** field list to display the field short_text1 on the admin interface, however this seems not to be working. The reason i am using get_object_or_404 is because there will be lots of fields in the **Assosiative** model and i would like the admin to display only the **fields** that have been checked as true on **Assosiative** model.

admin.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
    from django.contrib import admin
    from .models import Master, Label, Assosiative, Contact, Project
    from .forms import get_field_label

    class LabelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        #LabelAdminForm= get_field_label
        #form = LabelAdminForm
        l_asso = get_object_or_404(Assosiative, slug=slug)
        fields_list = []
        if l_asso.short_text1 == 1:
            fields_list.append('short_text1')
        if l_asso.short_text2 == 1:
            fields_list.append('short_text2')
        if l_asso.short_text3 == 1:
            fields_list.append('short_text3')
        if l_asso.short_text4 == 1:
           fields_list.append('short_text4')
        if l_asso.short_text5 == 1:
           fields_list.append('short_text5')
        fields = fields_list
        prepopulated_fields = {'slug':['assosiative']}
        class Meta:
            model = Label


    admin.site.register(Label, LabelAdmin)
```

models.py assosiative model

```
    class Assosiative(models.Model):
         form_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
         form_description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
         slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
         instructions = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
         heading1 = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
         short_text1 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
         short_text2 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
         short_text3 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
         short_text4 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
         short_text5 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

models.py Label model

```
      class Label(models.Model):
           assosiative = models.OneToOneField(Assosiative, unique=True)
           slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
           short_text1 = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
           short_text2 = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
           short_text3 = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
           short_text4 = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
           short_text5 = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ModelAdmin`'s [`get_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/_modules/django/contrib/admin/options/#ModelAdmin.get_fields) method. You don't need to use `get_object_or_404` to get association as it is already linked with current object passed to `get_fields` method.

```
class LabelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj is None:
            return super(LabelAdmin, self).get_fields(request, obj)
        fields = self.fields or list()
        fields = list(fields)    # to make copy of original list
        for x in xrange(1, 6):
            fields.remove('short_text{}'.format(x))
        if obj.assosiative.short_text1 == 1:
            fields.append('short_text1')
        if obj.assosiative.short_text2 == 1:
            fields.append('short_text2')
        if obj.assosiative.short_text3 == 1:
            fields.append('short_text3')
        if obj.assosiative.short_text4 == 1:
            fields.append('short_text4')
        if obj.assosiative.short_text5 == 1:
            fields.append('short_text5')
        return fields    
    class Meta:
        model = Label
```

Comment: django admin complains NoneType' object has no attribute 'assosiative'. Any help be highly appreciated

Comment: The above answer seems to work however when i try to add a new object to the Label model via the  admin interface it complains that NoneType' object has no attribute 'assosiative'.

Comment: @ Muhammad Tahir Thanks very much. Your answer solved my problem!